# How do you cimport the libc raise function?

Tags: cython

I could list everything I've tried, but it always ends up conflicting with the Python 'raise' keyword.

There is a strange definition in libc/signal.pxd:

```
int          raise_"raise" (int signum)
```

but I can't figure how to cimport and use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point of renaming the function to `raise_` is to avoid the name clash with python's keyword `raise`.

In python call the used name should be `raise_`, in the C-code produced by Cython the name will be `raise` (but there is no longer a conflict with Python keywords).

I.e. it can be used as follow:

```py
%%cython

from libc.signal cimport raise_
...
   raise_(1)
```